# Pandas panel data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python panel that is index by integer values. 
in dict form it would look like this:

```
{1:{1:series,2: series,3:series,4:series} 2:{1:series,2:series,3:series,4:series}...}
```

I would like to roll through my data by date and on each date take a time slice in the past apply a function to every time series so I get a result such as this where X is the output of the function of timeslice.

```
  1 2 3 4 ...
1 X X X X
2 X X X X
3 X X X X
4 X X X X
```

I thought `pandas.Panel.apply(func)` would do this but it does not.  I  only get a result in 1 seemingly random column.   I can iterate with for loops but i was hoping there was a faster and easier way of doing this.

I have a panel that looks like this:

```
 <class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
 Dimensions: 1000 (items) x 3714 (major) x 1000 (minor)
 Items: 1 to 1000
 Major axis: 1997-09-10 00:00:00 to 2012-06-19 00:00:00  
 Minor axis: 1 to 1000
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you put the data in a `Panel`? If you do then `data.apply(f, axis=time_ax)` (where `time_ax` is the time axis) should do the trick. Otherwise please post more context / data / examples of what's not working.

Comment: Thanks Wes. I really appreciate it and all of the work on the library. I added a panel to my question. if I have a panel like the above, should I just be able to do data.apply(numpy.mean,axis=data.major_axis)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a Python lamba function, to achieve that, as evidenced in the following link:
http://pandas.sourceforge.net/dataframe.html#function-application

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it. I am just having issues with the panel data structure.